# Protractor tests fail from time to time

Tags: javascript, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I write an end to end tests using protractor for my application. I'm sure that tests should be correct. But I see errors: `ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible`, `Expected false to be true`, `No element found using locator` from time to time.

Here is test code:

```
describe "try test message center and it", ->
  beforeEach ->
    ptor = protractor.getInstance()
    ptor.ignoreSynchronization = true

  it "should login", ->
    browser.driver.get homeURL
    browser.manage().window().maximize()
    element(`by`.xpath('//select/option[2]')).click()
    element(`by`.css('.buttons input')).click()

  it "should url is as expected", ->
    ptor = protractor.getInstance()
    expectedUrl = homeURL + '#/messages' 
    expect(ptor.getCurrentUrl()).toBe(expectedUrl)

  it "should create and send new message", ->
    ptor = protractor.getInstance()
    ptor.sleep 1000
    element(`by`.css('button.btn-primary')).click()
    element(`by`.model('uiData.createRecipient')).sendKeys 'James'
    ptor.sleep 1000
    element.all(`by`.repeater('match in matches')).get(1).click()
    element(`by`.model('uiData.createSubject')).sendKeys 'subject 2'
    element(`by`.model('uiData.createText')).sendKeys 'body of message'
    ptor.sleep 1000
    element(`by`.css('div.form-group a.btn-primary')).click()
    ptor.sleep 1000
    expect(element(`by`.css('.popupBox')).isPresent()).toBe(true)

  it "should check new message", ->
    ptor = protractor.getInstance()
    ptor.get('#/messages?folder=1')
    ptor.driver.navigate().refresh()
    ptor.sleep 5000
    element(`by`.model('uiData.to')).sendKeys 'k'
    ptor.sleep 3000
    element.all(`by`.cssContainingText('span.grid-col-to', 'James')).last().click()
    ptor.sleep 1000
    expect(element(`by`.xpath('//*[text()[contains(.,"body of message")]]')).isPresent()).toBe(true)
    element(`by`.xpath('//*[text()[contains(.,"Own it!")]]')).click()
    ptor.sleep 1000
    expect(element(`by`.cssContainingText('span', 'Owned by')).isPresent()).toBe(true)
    element(`by`.xpath('//*[text()[contains(.,"Disown it")]]')).click()
    ptor.sleep 1000
    expect(element(`by`.cssContainingText('span', 'Disowned by')).isPresent()).toBe(true)
```

Protractor v1.0.0,
Grunt protractor runner v1.0.1
Node v0.10.28,
NPM v1.4.9,
Chrome driver v2.10,
Selenium Server v2.42.2.
Tests running by Jenkins under Windows Server 2008 R2

What could it be? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Two tips that might help.

1. Set the windowsize in your protractor.conf.js, so the size of window is always the same and should always show the same elements.
2. Use a html with screenshot reporter so you can see what was on the screen when any case fails.

Both tips even work for phantomjs.
Add the following to the protractor.conf.js

```
onPrepare: function () {
    // The require statement must be down here, since jasmine-reporters
    // needs jasmine to be in the global and protractor does not guarantee
    // this until inside the onPrepare function.
    var browserName,
        platform,
        window = browser.manage().window();

    require('jasmine-reporters');
    require('protractor-html-screenshot-reporter');

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmine.ConsoleReporter());
    // create a html reporter with screenshots
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
        baseDirectory: 'reports/screenshots'   ,
        takeScreenShotsOnlyForFailedSpecs: true
    }));

    // set the window size
    browser.getCapabilities().then(function (capabilities) {
            browserName = capabilities.caps_.browserName;
            platform = capabilities.caps_.platform;
        }
    ).then(function getCurrentWindowSize() {
            return window.getSize();
        }
    ).then(function setWindowSize(dimensions) {
            var windowWidth = 1980,
                windowHeight = 1200;

            return window.setSize(windowWidth, windowHeight);
        }
    ).then(function getUpdatedWindowSize() {
            return window.getSize();
        }
    ).then(function showWindowSize(dimensions) {
            console.log('Browser:', browserName, 'on', platform, 'at', dimensions.width + 'x' + dimensions.height);
            console.log('Running e2e tests...');
        }
    );


},
```

Answer (score 1):

If you move or resize the window, it can hide elements that Protractor is looking for. Alternatively, Protractor sometimes moves on to the next line of code before all the elements on the page are *visually* finished loading. Since Protractor simulates a human user, it refuses to interact with hidden elements.

Also, you should really avoid using sleep whenever possible.